# I'm trying to import JTextField, JComboBox and JDateCalendar on a text file then storing it directly unto a table

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

Here I am trying to make a school management system for my project, I need some help in storing data in a text file and using it as a database, all in while storing all those data unto a table on another `JFrame`.

My code manages to print all the necessary inputs of the user to the text file, but I'm having a hard time coding the portion of importing data on the table. In summary, I need a single button to perform both operations of storing data in the textfile and importing it through the table.

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String student = JStudName.getText();
    String fathername = JFatherName.getText();
    String mothername = JMotherName.getText();
    String phonenumber = JPhoneNum.getText();
    Date birth = JBirth.getDate();
    String gender = JGender.getItemAt(WIDTH);
    String course = JCourse.getItemAt(WIDTH);
    String section = JSection.getItemAt(WIDTH);
    Date enrollment = JEnrollment.getDate();
    String id = JId.getText();
    String email = JEmail.getText();
    String address = JAddress.getText();
   try
   {   
       if (student.isEmpty() || fathername.isEmpty() || mothername.isEmpty() || phonenumber.isEmpty() || birth.equals("") || enrollment.equals("") || id.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || address.isEmpty()){
          
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Some fields are Empty, please fill the whole form.");
        }
       
       FileWriter Writer = new FileWriter("Records.txt", true);
       Writer.write(student   + fathername    + mothername  + phonenumber + (dateFormat.format(birth)) +  gender + course +  section + 
      (dateFormat.format(enrollment)) + id +  email +  address);
       Writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
       Writer.close();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Records Saved");
   }    catch (IOException ex) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "failed to save");
        }
   
     String filePath = "C:\\Users\\zeptr\\Desktop\\Exmundo_Kurt\\School Record Information System\\Records.txt";
     File file = new File(filePath);

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)JDatabase.getModel();
            Object[] lines =  br.lines().toArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
                String[] row = lines[i].toString().split(" ");
                model.addRow(row);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RecordsDashboard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: So, you're working in a OO language.  You should be taking advantage of this and creating a POJO of the data you wish to "share".  Also, without any kind of delimiter in you file, you're going to find it impossible to read back the contents.  You'd be better of using XML or JSON (or at a pinch CSV).  If you need to perform to actions, then you should write two methods, which your `actionPerformed` method can call

Comment: There is no need to reload the entire text file.  Just write the data to the file then use addRow() method of the DefaultTableModel to add the new data. Also, your write statement makes no sense to me. You don't add any delimiters between each piece of data you write to the file. So how will you ever be able to parse the data the next time your read it in?

Comment: The terrible `Date`, `DateFormat`, and other legacy date-time classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: Following Java naming conventions will make your code easier to read. Variable names should begin with a lowercase letter. So `jFatherName`, not `JFatherName`.

Comment: wait guys, my prof only accepts us utilizing file handling at the moment. So as alternative for the supposed to be sql file, i need a text file to incorporate those said data's and possible alter using buttons while it updates the table too..

Comment: What are the current errors in your code?